# Qual é a utilidade das funções com underline (_) ao final?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Considere as funções dos seguintes *packages*:

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

gorup_by_

summarise_

mutate_

transmute_
```

**tidyr**

```
library(tidyr)

gather_

spread_

separate_

unite_
```

- Qual é a utilidade destas funções?
- Quando devo utilizá-las em detrimento das outras funções sem o *underline* ao final?

`data.frame` reproduzível:

```
set.seed(4321)

dataset <- data.frame(replicate(6, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
                      X7 = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 10, 3))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O motivo dessas funções existirem ainda hoje é histórico.

O `dplyr` foi pensando em quem programa interativamente, por isso ele fornece algumas facilidades para quem está programando como:

- não ter que usar aspas para colocar o nome das variáveis
- não usar o nome do data.frame o tempo todo.

Exemplos:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = cyl*2)

mtcars$cyl <- mtcars$cyl * 2
```

Isso faz com que o usuário seja mais produtivo na hora que está programando. O que torna isso possível é o uso do que é chamado de *Non Standard Evaluation* (NSE). NSE faz com que seja mais agradável programar interativamente, mas torna o código mais complicado quando você quer criar funções mais gerais.

Por exemplo, não é muito intuitivo como fazer no `dplyr` se você quiser que o nome de uma nova variável venha do valor de uma variável:

```
> variavel <- "cyl"
> 
> mtcars %>% 
+   mutate(variavel = variavel *2)
Error in variavel * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

O `dplyr` não usa o valor `cyl` da variável. Na verdade ele está tentando criar uma nova variável chamada `variavel` cujo valor será `"cyl" * 2` e isso dá um erro.

Durante o tempo, os autores do `dplyr` propuseram diversas formas de resolver esse problema. Uma delas foi incluir as funções equivalentes mas com um `_` no final.

Essas funções usavam *Standard Evaluation* e portanto, eram úteis na hora de criar as suas próprias funções, o que é chamado de *programar* com `dplyr`.

Veja como era esquisita a sintaxe usando o `mutate_` por exemplo:

```
variavel <- "cyl"
mtcars %>% 
  mutate_(
    .dots = 
      list(lazyeval::interp(~ 2*(var), var = as.name(variavel))) %>% setNames(variavel)
    )
```

No entanto agora o `dplyr` usa um conceito chamado [*Tidy Evaluation*](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/) e essa é agora a forma recomendada de se programar com `dplyr`. Exemplo:

```
variavel <- "cyl"
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(!!sym(variavel) := 2*!!sym(variavel))
```

Em resumo, respondendo as suas perguntas:

- Elas eram úteis para se programar com `dplyr`.
- Não devem ser utilizadas. A forma recomendada é usar Tidy Evaluation.

Você pode encontrar [aqui](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/7ada5340d475ad0296a05bd607d906f39c67d430/vignettes/nse.Rmd) a versão da *vignette* que introduziu essa conceito.

Hoje em dia a documentação do `dplyr` sobre essas funções diz:

> dplyr used to offer twin versions of each verb suffixed with an
>   underscore. These versions had standard evaluation (SE) semantics:
>   rather than taking arguments by code, like NSE verbs, they took
>   arguments by value. Their purpose was to make it possible to program
>   with dplyr. However, dplyr now uses tidy evaluation semantics. NSE
>   verbs still capture their arguments, but you can now unquote parts of
>   these arguments. This offers full programmability with NSE verbs.
>   Thus, the underscored versions are now superfluous.